# Create a desktop app from a collection of webpages

Tags: web, tabs

So I have the following problem: I have several web tools that I use for organizing myself.
Eg. Todoist, Google Calendar, and Clockify.

Ideally, I would like all those tools to act as one application. With integrations enabled, they almost do. The problem is, if I open them as tabs in my browser, inevitably something gets closed, unrelated tabs get opened, etc. In other words, the cohesiveness is lost.

The best potential solution that I can think of is a tool that creates a native/desktop application from a collection of web pages. So, given links to Todoist, GCal, and Clockify it would create an app with 3 tabs/screens.

Is there a tool out there that can do that? Or are there other options?

Comment: You don't specify which browser you use, but assuming you use Chrome you can set your **startup pages**. Essentially, set the startup option to "Open a specific set of pages" and then the tabs you specify will always open on startup if not already open. Is this satisfactory? Presumably, most modern browsers have this feature. The specific instructions for Chrome are: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Assuming you're on Win10 you can also make use of the virtual desktops feature, and keep a browser open on your second desktop with your 3 productivity tabs, and do your other web browsing in your main desktop. https://community.windows.com/en-us/stories/virtual-desktop-windows-10

Comment: startup tabs aren't quite it, because I like to reopen my previous tabs

Comment: You could leave your startup option as "Continue where you left off" then and create a batch file to open the 3 webpages. This website shows the batch file to write, and I tested it for myself; all my current tabs are still there and the specified sites in the file open as well. https://www.mobigyaan.com/how-to-open-multiple-websites-using-a-desktop-shortcut